# Keep UIViewControllers reference, while making network request after user dismissed VC

Tags: ios, swift

Let's say we have a ViewController, that is responsible for making a network request.

This ViewController starts making network request, and user dismisses VC while network request hasn't finished yet.

Is it possible to retain VC in memory after user demises it until network request is finished?

And I would prefer to keep network request inside VC instead of some repository or singleton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but this would constitute as a memory leak and you wouldn't be able to deallocate the VC once the API call finishes without some unnecessary acrobatics (e.g. keep a reference to the VC somewhere outside like appDelegate, wait for the API call to finish, then let the delegate know it can release the reference).

If you need the data from the API call, but don't need the controller that initiates it, then something like the repository or singleton like you suggest, or like an interactor design pattern would be better.